# Установка QNX - нужен образ системы

Tags: установка, образ, qnx

Собственно, скачал qnx sdp, в состав которого и должна входить ОС, как я понял. Но при монтировании образа можно установить только пакет для разработки под эту систему. А где взять образ системы я так и не понял. Извините, если задаю глупый вопрос.